# Failied to building Linux kernel module for specific kernel version

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I am trying to build an LKM for linux 4.15.0-23-generic. I am using following command to make it.

> make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules

Unfortunately, make fails to get the correct header files.

> WARNING: "unwind_get_return_address_ptr" [/home/probir/hyperf/hyperf/hyperf.ko] undefined!
> WARNING: "__kernel_text_address" [/home/probir/hyperf/hyperf/hyperf.ko] undefined!
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic'

Header files are located in following directory.

> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/unwind.h
>
> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic/include/linux/kernel.h

Why make is failing to locate the header, even if correct version is given?

Comment: Headers have absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: If there are missing headers, you get a very straightforward error message that **talks about missing headers** in a way you cannot miss. Since you've got a totally different kind of message, there are no missing headers.

Comment: Also see [this](/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Comment: Thanks, got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

These functions ([unwind_get_return_address_ptr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.18/source/arch/x86/kernel/unwind_frame.c#L22) and [__kernel_text_address](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.18/source/kernel/extable.c#L105)) are **not exported** (via `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or so), so they cannot be used by *modules*. Only a code *compiled into kernel* itself may use given symbols.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that they cannot be used by modules. Those symbols are required to find (**kallsyms_lookup_name**) before use.

Comment: @ProbirRoy: Strictly speaking, you are right. But using `kallsyms_lookup_name` you may use almost anything, including things which are not intended (by kernel developers) to be used outside. So I don't think that a note about that function is needed here.